# xcode crashes all the time !

Tags: xcode

I have crazy problem with xcode 4 when ever I want build and run my app IF the simulator be open xcode crashes !!!!! I never had this problem , I unistall the xcode 4.0 and then install new version 4.0.2 but still has this problem !

[image]

```
    ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEKit/IDEKit-303/Framework/Classes/Workspace/IDEWorkspaceTabController.m:2327
Details:  Assertion failed: [suppressionTargetValue isEqualToString:_kUserDefaults_IDESuppressStopExecutionWarningTargetValue_Add]
Object:   <IDEWorkspaceTabController: 0x201464400>
Method:   -_showWarningForBuild:forOtherExecution:trackersToStop:taskActionBlock:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x200020700>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000100949773 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010006d394 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x0000000100931e02 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _showWarningForBuild:forOtherExecution:trackersToStop:taskActionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
  3  0x00000001008e830b -[IDEWorkspaceTabController _performContextTask:command:commandName:] (in IDEKit)
  4  0x00007fff88486e9a -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
  5  0x00000001001cf63c -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
  6  0x000000010085b656 -[IDEApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in IDEKit)
  7  0x00007fff884ab41e -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] (in AppKit)
  8  0x00007fff884ab188 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] (in AppKit)
  9  0x00007fff88490e09 -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:] (in AppKit)
 10  0x00007fff8848fbb1 -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:] (in AppKit)
 11  0x00007fff88360645 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 12  0x000000010085b36e -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 13  0x00007fff882f74da -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 14  0x00007fff882f01a8 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 15  0x0000000100000eec
 16  0x0000000000000002
```

Comment: Having the same problem, just started today.  Really frustrating.

Comment: I do not know what's going on !!! really ridicules

Comment: This appears to be project nonspecific.  I can run any project once, and the second time, it crashes.  Also tried rebooting, reinstalling xcode, no luck.

Comment: As a workaround, it will run for me if I hit the stop button in the IDE first.  Still a hassle if I forget.

Comment: I filed a bug with Apple, you should do the same.  They prioritize based on how many reports they get.  http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: uow! my xcode just stopped raising the error and I still have no idea why! I didn't update xcode or changed any configuration... weird

Comment: well, january 2015 and it still crashes all the time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XCode - Preference - General - Dialog Warnings - Reset "Don`t Ask Me" Warnings button Click!

I solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Disk's permissions.  Start Disk Utility and do Verify Disk and Repair Permissions.